# Restore postgresql 9.5 backup to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, sql-server-2014, postgresql-9.5

I have backup file from PostgreSQL 9.5 version and want to restore it into SQL Server.

I tried with import tier but getting error.

I have ".backup" file extension of PostgreSQL.

Comment: What do you mean by "backup"? An actual binary backup or a dump file? A *binary backup* is a copy of the database's data pages. You can't use it from other products. Sometimes you can't even use it from one DB version to another. Dumps on the other hand are SQL scripts of the schema and data, written in the *database's dialect*. **NO** database provides full Standard SQL support. You can't use them from one product to the other because they use different types, syntax. Eg PostgreSQL uses the non-standard `nextval` when SQL Server has the more standard `NEXT VALUE FOR`.

Comment: On the other hand PostgreSQL's `timestamp` corresponds to `datetime2` while SQL Server's `timestamp` is a deprecated name for `rowversion`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You *DON'T* need backups or dumps to move data from one database to another, or replicate data. You can use eg SQL Server's Integration Services to pull data from multiple sources (including PostgreSQL) and insert it into targets (eg SQL Server or PostgreSQL tables). Or you can link the databases to query data from both databases

Comment: Not possible. The custom format can't be used for anything else then `pg_restore` and the plain SQL dump will have so many differences to the syntax that SQL Server understands that it will be **very** hard (if not impossible) to automate changes in that file.